# Why do START and TOP work unexpectedly for gravity of Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, gravity, layout-gravity

I have done some experiments with Relative Layout gravity in Android Studio. I am very perplexed with results gotten. Let's look at my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top" >
    <Button
        android:text="Apple"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I set *android:gravity* to *left*, *right*, or *bottom* I get the proper gravity effects. The view is moved to left, right or bottom correspondingly. However if I set *android:gravity* to *top* I get no any visible effect.

There are several other oddities for me. Value *left*, *right*, *end* moves the view but value *start* doesn't.  Why?  IMHO if we use LTR the "start" has to be equal to the *left*.  I know that value *start|top* is the default value for gravity but it doesn't help me to understand the problem.  Please help me to clarify the situation.  Thank you.

Comment: I recommend that you focus on `ConstraintLayout`. I am not aware of anything that `RelativeLayout` offered that `ConstraintLayout` fails to offer. `ConstraintLayout` is where Google is investing in ongoing improvements and bug fixes. And `ConstraintLayout` comes from a library, so your results can be more consistent across Android OS versions.

Comment: With regards to your specific problem, it is possible that you are the first person to ever try using `android:gravity` with `RelativeLayout`. `android:gravity` was added for other types of containers (`FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc.). You do not need it with `RelativeLayout`, as with `RelativeLayout` you use more explicit rules to specify the sizing and positioning of its children. I am not certain that the rules for `android:gravity` on `RelativeLayout` are well-defined.